# How can I shift shapes?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to declare a custom shape

```
\radius \pgf@xa=\pgf@x 
\centerpoint \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
\pgfpathcircle{\centerpoint}{\radius/10}
\pgfpathmoveto{\centerpoint}
\pgfpathellipse{\centerpoint}{\pgfpoint{\radius/2-\radius/10}{0}}{\pgfpoint{0}{\radius/10}}
\pgfpathellipse{\centerpoint}{\pgfpoint{\radius/2-\radius/10}{0}}{\pgfpoint{0}{\radius/10}}
```

The custom shape will inherit from circle.
I have the following questions:

1. How can I fill the circle,ellipse etc with the given color?
2. How can I shift the center point of the first ellipse with radius/2 left and the second radius/2 right?

Comment: Is this a TikZ or a PGF question? Do you know of the `ellipse` shape from the `shapes.geometric` library that also includes a proper anchor border? What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to stroke or fill or shade or clip the path you have created. Here is a quick mock-up (though it's a little too quick, the path modes are really hacky. There are more proper ways of doing it. Just check the shapes library). For shifting points you can use `\pgfpointadd` or `\pgfpointdiff` etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{circse}{
\inheritsavedanchors[from=circle]
\inheritanchorborder[from=circle]
\inheritanchor[from=circle]{center}
\backgroundpath{
\radius 
\pgf@xa=\pgf@x 
\centerpoint \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
\pgfpathcircle{\centerpoint}{\radius/10}
%\pgfpathmoveto{\centerpoint}
\pgfpathellipse{\pgfpointadd{\centerpoint}{\pgfpoint{10pt}{0pt}}}{\pgfpoint{\radius/2-\radius/10}{0}}{\pgfpoint{0}{\radius/10}}
\pgfpathellipse{\pgfpointadd{\centerpoint}{\pgfpoint{-10pt}{0pt}}}{\pgfpoint{\radius/2-\radius/10}{0}}{\pgfpoint{0}{\radius/10}}
\begingroup
\tikz@mode

\iftikz@mode@fill
    \iftikz@mode@draw
    \pgfusepath{fill,draw}
    \else
    \pgfusepath{fill}
    \fi
\else
    \iftikz@mode@draw
    \pgfusepath{draw}
    \fi
\fi
\endgroup
}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circse,thick,draw=red,fill=yellow,scale=5] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Eh … The `backgroundpath` (and the foreground path) will be supplied with the options in `\pgfnode{<shape>}{<anchor>}{<text>}{<name>}{<This will be executed after the background and the foreground path have been constructed.>}`. Just do the path there and let TikZ/PGF do the rest. (It will add `\begingroup\tikz@finish`.)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I know it's just hack for making an example.